# Trying to fill blanks with alpha characters based on number above

Tags: excel, vba

I have this.

```
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
4
4.1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
5
```

I would like this.

```
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
4
4.1
4.A
4.B
4.C
4.D
5
```

I have about 22k rows to fill in.  How can I do it?  I put together the code below, bu tit doesn't do what I want.  I need to start over with prior number + 'A' whenever a new blank cell is found.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
Sub AlphaFill()
    Dim Cell, CellChars
    Dim Default, Prompt, Title
    Dim rangeSelected As Range
    Dim UpperCase As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rangeSelected = Range("F1:F21400")

    For Each Cell In rangeSelected

        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            i = 1
        End If

        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            CellChars = Chr(64 + i)
            If Not UpperCase Then CellChars = UCase(CellChars)
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value & CellChars
            i = i + 1
        End If

        Debug.Print Cell.Value

    Next

End Sub
```

The problem is, I can't seem to preserve the prior cell, for instance, the 4.A, 4.B, 4.C, and 4.D

Comment: Are you getting a Char value with `CellChars = CellChars + 1`? isn't it better to make: `CellChars = Chr(64 + i)` and `i = i +1`

Comment: Yeah, I caught that right after I posted my question.  I modified the script a bit.  It's close now, but still not working like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you need to store the last whole number you see  then use that on the next blank cell, resetting the counter between gaps:

```
Sub AlphaFill()
    Dim Cell            As Range
    Dim UpperCase       As Boolean
    Dim LastWholeNumber As String
    Dim LastLetter      As Long
    Dim CurrentNumber   As String

    UpperCase = True

    For Each Cell In Range("F1:F21400")
        CurrentNumber = Cell.Value

        If CurrentNumber = "" Then
            LastLetter = LastLetter + 1
            Cell.Value = LastWholeNumber & "." & ChrW$(LastLetter)
        ElseIf InStr(CurrentNumber, ".") = 0 Then
            '// whole number - store it & reset to A/a 
            LastLetter = IIf(UpperCase, 64, 97)
            LastWholeNumber = CurrentNumber
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it.  This works!!

```
Sub AlphaFill()
    Dim Cell, CellChars
    Dim Default, Prompt, Title
    Dim rangeSelected As Range
    Dim UpperCase As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rangeSelected = Range("F1:F21400")

    For Each Cell In rangeSelected

        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            KeepValue = Cell.Value
            i = 1
        End If

        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            CellChars = Chr(64 + i)
            If Not UpperCase Then CellChars = UCase(CellChars)
            Cell.Value = KeepValue & CellChars
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is as

[image]

Try this

```
Sub AlphaFill()
    Dim Cell, CellChars
    Dim Default, Prompt, Title
    Dim rangeSelected As Range
    Dim UpperCase As Boolean
    Dim charIndex As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rangeSelected = Range("F1:F21400")

    UpperCase = True
    charIndex = 65
    For Each Cell In rangeSelected
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            If InStr(Cell.Offset(-1, 0), ".") > 0 Then  'check if value contains "."
                Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Offset(-1, 0), WorksheetFunction.Find(".", Cell.Offset(-1, 0))) & Chr(charIndex) 'extract the string till "."
            Else
                Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(-1, 0) & "." & Chr(charIndex)  'get the number and add "."
            End If
            charIndex = charIndex + 1
        Else
            If charIndex <> 65 Then charIndex = 65  'if cell is not blank set charIndex to 65
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will give result as

[image]